# Input set of string from user in c#

Tags: c#

I am new in c#.So please help.

The first line of input has a unique integer N that indicates the number of sets of strings, each set may contain between 1 and 50 inclusive elements, and each of the strings of the set may contain between 1 and 50 inclusive characters.

How i take input from user above this condition??

example:

enter integer number:3

My dream is big

I want to go school

You are so sweet

Comment: what have you tried ? can you provide sample input ?

Comment: looks like homework.. https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/problems/view/1244

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do.

1. [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) the string into array.
2. [Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aw9s5t8f(v=vs.110).aspx) the array using an `IComparer` that compares the length of each string in the array
3. [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) the string array into a single string

See this function below:

```
public static string SortStringByLength(string input, Order order) {
    string[] words = input.Split(' ');
    if (order == Order.ASC)
        Array.Sort(words, (x, y) => x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length));
    else
        Array.Sort(words, (x, y) => y.Length.CompareTo(x.Length));

    return string.Join(" ", words);
}
```

And here's a [demo](http://rextester.com/JVNX69828) to see it in action.